# How is query working at Teradata?

Tags: sql, hive, teradata

I tried to run below query at teradata and It resulted as expected :

```
select column1 as c1Alias from my_table where column2 in ( c1Alias , 10 , 20 , 30) ;
```

But I tried to run same query on HIVE , It throws exception as given below :

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:44 Invalid table alias or column  reference 'c1Alias': (possible column names are: .......)
```

I am not surprised why it is failing at HIVE , but surprised how it is working on Teradata.

As per my understanding, Clauses are executed in order as WHERE >> SELECT. Apparently alias generated at SELECT clause would not be available for use in WHERE clause. Correct me if I am wrong here.

I really wanted to know how it is working in teradata ?

Comment: Teradata allows you to use an alias in the where clause, as well as group by and order by clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, logically any SELECT is processed in following order:

- FROM
- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- HAVING
- OLAP functions
- QUALIFY
- create SELECT column list
- SAMPLE
- ORDER BY

Besides the proprietary QUALIFY/SAMPLE every DBMS will do it exactly the same.

When you add a filter to the WHERE-condition the column list is not yet created, thus using an alias should fail (and will fail in almost every other DBMS, afaik only Access allows using it similar to Teradata).

It's not failing because Teradata is older than Standard SQL and this seems to be an relict of the query language Teradata implemented first.

But it's a nice extension (just never alias to an existing column name to avoid confusing the optimizer and/or end user) and you get used to it very fast, it avoids lots cut&paste or Derived Tables.

Answer (score 0):

The order of execution of SQL is explained very well over here:
https://www.eversql.com/sql-order-of-operations-sql-query-order-of-execution/

An excerpt from the post for your quick reference: (Credits to the author for covering all 10 parts of SQL)

1. FROM, including JOINs
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. WINDOW functions
6. SELECT
7. DISTINCT
8. UNION
9. ORDER BY

10.LIMIT and OFFSET