# How does a Teradata query evaluate alias in a where clause

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the same question as in the following link: [How is query working at Teradata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658664/how-is-query-working-at-teradata#_=)_

The answers in that thread didn't  really address my question.

In SQL Server, when I use an alias in a where statement, it gives an error. I understand why.

In Teradata, however, I don't get an error and it does evaluate the query perfectly as I want.

My question is: *how does Teradata handle this query. What technique does it use under the hood to still evaluate the alias in a where clause?*

Comment: Does Teradata allow all aliases in the WHERE clause? e.g. Will the below work? `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY X) AS RN FROM T WHERE Foo = 'Bar' AND RN = 1` - if so that will certainly be confusing semantics as the `WHERE Foo = 'Bar' ` predicate needs to be evaluated **before** the row numbering and the `RN = 1` part after it

Comment: @MartinSmith - no, that will not work, you cannot use a windowed function in a where clause, aliased or no.  This will work in Teradata though - `select a,b,c as foo from table where foo = ...`  You can use the alias in a qualify though.

Comment: I think you are thinking about the SQL statement and RDBMS query execution is a straight line connecting the two, but the path from SQL (a human language) to the selection and return of the data that the SQL describes is crazy complex.  The answer is merely: That's how they built it to work. Teradata parses the SQL and then goes through a bunch of steps to get to an optimized execution plan. This is probably done as part of the parsing phase and it's just a nice extra feature that the developers of the parsing engine added to save us humans a few steps.

Comment: @JNevill No, I don't think it is a straight line connecting SQL statements and RDBMS at all. I know it is crazy complex. F.e. Joins can be performed using, among others, the following algorithms: hash-join, nested loop join and the sort-merge join algorithms. The `ORDER BY` can be performed using a quick-sort or merge-sort algorithm etc. I am asking for a general explanation. I don't need to know how it EXACTLY does everything.

Comment: parsing engines are kind of black boxes, I doubt anyone has any of the details you're looking for.

Comment: You seem confused TBH. The various join and sort algorithms are different possible strategies for implementing logical execution plan operators. This is completely separate from syntax rules for specifying a query. Note the **logical** order of execution described in your linked question is absolutely not the same as physical order of execution. It is just a mental model for thinking about SQL. The optimiser for example would be entirely free to execute a sort before a join even though the `order by` is last in the logical order of execution

Comment: Roughly speaking: Teradata tries to resolve unqualified names to column references first. Then it will effectively replace each alias with the expression it names. So if the expression is allowed in that context, so is the alias.